# application crashing (Intersection of two linked list)

Tags: c, crash, linked-list, intersection

I am supposed to create two linked list and add data to that list and show intersection of two list.(common data in both the list.)

I don't know why when i try to create the first list it works fine and when i try to create the second list it crashes

Here the following function do following things

- create list - To create two lists.
- addnode - To add nodes to both the list.
- intersectionlist - This shows intersection of two lists.
- freed - Free all nodes.
- displayed - Display both the list.

And the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *list1 = NULL, *list2 = NULL;
void create_list()
{
    int ch;
    struct node *tempnode;
    printf("Enter one to create list one or two to create list two\n");
marker:
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    if(ch != 1 && ch != 2)
    {
        printf("wrong input\n");
        printf("Please enter again\n");
        goto marker;
    }
    if(ch == 1)
    {
        tempnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("sucesss");
        if(tempnode == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation unsuccessful\n");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter the data to be inserted\n");
        scanf("%d",tempnode->data);
        if(list1 == NULL)
        {
            tempnode->next = NULL;
            list1 = tempnode;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("List one already created\n");
            free(tempnode);
        }
    }

    if(ch == 2)
    {
        tempnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(tempnode == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation unsuccessful\n");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter the data to be inserted\n");
        scanf("%d",tempnode->data);
        if(list2 == NULL)
        {
            tempnode->next = NULL;
            list2 = tempnode;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("List two already created\n");
            free(tempnode);
        }
    }
}

void addnode()
{
    int ch;
    struct node *tempnode;
    printf("Enter one to add node to list one or two to add node to list two\n");
marker:
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    if(ch != 1 && ch != 2)
    {
        printf("wrong input\n");
        printf("Please enter again\n");
        goto marker;
    }
    if(ch == 1)
    {
        tempnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(tempnode == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation unsuccessful\n");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter the data to be inserted\n");
        scanf("%d",tempnode->data);
        if(list1 != NULL)
        {
            tempnode->next = list1;
            list1 = tempnode;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("List not created yet please create list\n");
            getch();
            free(tempnode);
        }
    }

    if(ch == 2)
    {
        tempnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(tempnode == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation unsuccessful\n");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter the data to be inserted\n");
        scanf("%d",tempnode->data);
        if(list2 != NULL)
        {
            tempnode->next = list2;
            list2 = tempnode;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("List not created yet please create list\n");
            getch();
            free(tempnode);
        }
    }

}

void intersection_list()
{
    int flag = 0;
    struct node *tempnode1, *tempnode2;
    if((list1 == NULL) || (list2 == NULL))
    {
        printf("One of both the list is empty\n");
    }
    for(tempnode1 = list1; tempnode1 != NULL; tempnode1 = tempnode1->next)
    {
        for(tempnode2 = list2; tempnode2 != NULL; tempnode2 = tempnode2->next)
        {
            if(tempnode1->data == tempnode2->data)
            {
                if(flag == 0)
                {
                    printf("The union of list one and list two is\n");
                }
                printf("\t%d",tempnode2->data);
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0)
    {
        printf("There is no same data in both the list\n");
    }

}

void freed()
{
    int count = 0;
    struct node *tempnode;
    while(list1 != NULL)
    {
        tempnode = list1;
        list1 = list1->next;
        free(tempnode);
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d nodes freed from list 1\n",count);

    count = 0;
    while(list2 != NULL)
    {
        tempnode = list2;
        list2 = list2->next;
        free(tempnode);
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d nodes freed from list 2\n",count);
}

void displayed()
{
    int ch;
    struct node *tempnode;
    printf("Enter one to display list one and enter two to display list two\n");
marker:
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    if(ch != 1 && ch != 2)
    {
        printf("wrong input\n");
        printf("Please enter again\n");
        goto marker;
    }
    if(ch == 1)
    {
        if(list1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("Empty list\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The data in list one\n");
            for(tempnode = list1; tempnode != NULL; tempnode = tempnode->next)
            {
                printf("\t%d\n",tempnode->data);
            }
        }

    }

    if(ch == 2)
    {
        if(list2 == NULL)
        {
            printf("Empty list\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The data in list two\n");
            for(tempnode = list2; tempnode != NULL; tempnode = tempnode->next)
            {
                printf("\t%d\n",tempnode->data);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the option number for the execution\n1. Create list\n2. Add node\n3. Intersection of list\n4. Display list\n5. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(ch == 1)
        {
            create_list();
        }
        else
        {
            if(ch == 2)
            {
                addnode();
            }
            else
            {
                if(ch == 3)
                {
                    intersection_list();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(ch == 4)
                    {
                        displayed();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while(ch < 5 && ch > 0);
    freed();
}
```

Comment: First thing I laid eyes on: `goto marker;`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &tempnode->data)`

Comment: fvalcin whats wrong with that i didn't get you please explain
agbinfo tempnode is a pointer so & is not required right?
I am just new to programming.

Comment: @SaranSankaran there is zero-reason to implement this with a goto, and before you rely on functions like `scanf()`, you need to understand how they work. The list of things wrong in this code is significant, but some things are absolutely core. For example: You omit checking the results of the api's you're calling. Ex: What does `scanf()` *return*, and how could that be used functionally in this program? Finally, asking someone to debug a 270-line wall of code is rather presumptive. Have *you* made efforts to debug this yet? If so, what did you discover? If not, *why not?*

Comment: ... continued. Its not all bad, btw. You're pointer work, especially for a beginner, isn't bad at all. Sketchy in a few places, but still, better than many that are just starting to learn pointers. Thats a steep learning hurdle, and you seem to be doing well with it.

Comment: @SaranSankaran `tempnode` is a pointer but `*tempnode` refers to the value. So `(*tempnode).data` is also a value. `tempnode->` is a shortcut for `(*tempnode)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes actually i am using DEV Cpp as my compiler and in that i guess there is no way u can debug inside a function i just set my cursor after declaration section and hit run to cursor but when a function is called it just goes to next line in main and not inside that function so i was unsuccessful in debugging all the functions.<p>

Comment: @agbinfo yeah i realised it was just a silly mistake and thank you for explaining :) working fine now
and 
WhozCraig I wanted to go again to the scanf function so i used goto function. I didn't use return value of the scanf as I didn't realise the error would be with scanf function. Thanks for letting me know my mistake. I still didn't get my mistake with goto statement.

Comment: @SaranSankaran there's no "mistake" with the `goto` in the sense that it does the work. The problem is that there's almost always a better way than using a `goto`. In your case, a `do... while` loop would have better expressed what you were trying to do.

Comment: Ok got it thank you for your valuable helps and suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

hope this may help

```
void inter(Node* a, Node* b, struct Linkedlist* res)
{
    if(a!=NULL&&b!=NULL)
    {
        if(a->data == b->data)
        {
             nodePushBack(res, a->data);
             inter(a->next, b->next, res);
        }
        else if(a->data < b->data)
        {
             inter(a->next, b, res);
        }
        else
        {
            inter(a, b->next, res);
        }
    }
}
```